# GetTypes() doesn't return classes which implement interface in another project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-assembly

I have 3 projects :

- StartUp
- Contracts (with shared interfaces)
- Models

Models has classes that uses interfaces in Contracts.
StartUp references Contracts and Models.

When i'm trying to register, in dependency injection, all classes that uses `IGetter<>` (interface in Contracts), StartUp doesn't see Models with this code:

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).ToList()
```

Comment: Has the relevant assembly been loaded at that point?

Comment: Given that you only have three projects that you're interested in, I'd just specify those assemblies directly as a first step, e.g. via `typeof` to get at one type in each assembly, then the `Assembly` property.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc said i have to load the assembly first. I'm sure there is a better solution but i write and `Assembly.Load("Models");` before trying to get my Types.

Thanks Marc.

Comment: Instead of loading the assemblies by name you might just do `GC.KeepAlive(typeof(SomeTypeFromTheModelsAssembly));` to load it

Comment: Why should i do that ?

Comment: Before the JIT compiles a method, it ensures that all referenced assemblies are loaded. If you do `typeof(SomeTypeFromTheModelsAssembly)`, the JIT ensures that the Models assembly is loaded before the method containing it is executed. However, either the C# compiler or JIT compiler might remove unused code as an optimization. The use of `GC.KeepAlive(...)` prevents the C# and JIT compiler from removing that "unused" reference.